# How to change template of controller rendered in twig file (Symfony 3)?

Tags: symfony, templates, controller, twig, overriding

I know that we can render the content of a controller in twig file like this:

`{{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Security:login',{"baseTemplate": true})) }}`

However, I don't know if we can pass the new template so that the controller will use it instead of the default. Anyone tried to override template in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand the issue here

If you do

```
{{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Security:login',{"baseTemplate": true})) }}
```

You could aswell do:

```
{{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Security:login',{"template": "your_template.html.twig"})) }}
```

Or

```
{{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Security:login',{"templateNumber": "4"})) }}
```

Where templateNumber is used in a condition inside your controller ?